# Vim keybindings for nautilus

Tags: nautilus, vim, nautilus-elementary, shortcut-keys

Is there a way to configure nautilus to use vim keybdings.

By vim keybindings I am not saying just <kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>j</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> but other things like regex search on filenames too.

I know I can simply use a command line, but sometimes I have to use this crap file browser for browsing the directories.

Or is there any other GUI file browser which has customizability?

Answer (score 4):

You can try ranger or vifm - if you're not afraid of the ncurses gui :)

Comment: This sounds good. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

There's an old manager called rox-filer wich have some keyboard friendly features.

'.' opens an input textbox to select files by a wildcard

'/' opens an input textbox to navigate filesystem using directory names and featuring tab text completion.

'!' opens an input to execute a command in the current dir. if there's a selection it will add a "$@" which it's replaced by all the files selected.

Features also keyboard navigation and selection of files. And it's light and fast.

The process forks on invocation so you can open it from the console and continue using it.

It's not a nautilus replacement but a handy tool to have.